# Open Server 5.0.7 - What does the cleanup shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, kernel, sh, panic

I run an Open Server 5.0.7. There is a cleanup script which is running every sunday.
When executing the script I get a kernal panic. Can someone help me to understand the script?
I'm pretty new to shell scripting.

```
# Clean up super-user log.
cp /usr/adm/sulog /usr/adm/Osulog
> /usr/adm/sulog

# If accounting isn't enabled, clean up wtmp and wtmpx,
# being careful not to create them if they don't exist.
if  [ -x /usr/lib/acct/acct_enable ] && /usr/lib/acct/acct_enable -cs ; then
  : Do nothing - accounting will clean up wtmp and wtmpx
else
  [ -f /etc/wtmp ] && >/etc/wtmp
  [ -f /etc/wtmpx ] && >/etc/wtmpx
fi


# Clean up miscellaneous files.
find / -type f -name core -atime +7 -local -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Can someone help me? I don't know what happened here.

Comment: Check out [Explainshell](https://explainshell.com/)

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot

Comment: I don't see anything in that script that's likely to cause a kernel panic.

Comment: @tech: IMHO, the only piece of code which, in theory, could cause the problem, might be `acct_enable`, on the grounds that this is (aside from the innocent `rm`) the only external command being called. I would add a `set -x` and redirect stdin and stdout of the script to some file, and after you rebooted from the kernel panic, you can see from this file at least at which point execution failed.

Comment: @user1934428 That I know how to it right.... so you mean set -x before every command? And then something like this: ./cleanup > cleanup.log 2>&1? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this....  And could you tell me what -local does? If I execute it on my other linux system I get an error "find: unknown predicate `-local".
Thanks

Comment: Of course not! Once in the beginning, and then `-x` stays active for the whole script. The redirection is correct. `-local` is not a valid option for `find`. See `man find` for a description of all options.